# If the KL divergence is not a metric or a measure, what is it?

Tags: definition, kullback-leibler, metric, variational-bayes

The KL divergence is not a metric because e.g. it does not satisfy the symmetry property that metrics posses. According to [the definition of measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)), the KL divergence doesn't seem to be a measure, although [the related Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) introduces the KL divergence as "a measure of how one probability distribution is different from a second". So, mathematically, what is the KL divergence?

Note that I know how the KL divergence is defined, so don't tell me how it's defined.

Comment: It is a measure in the *English* sense. You can use the word the way the Wikipedia article does. You just have to avoid confusing measure theorists. :)

Comment: It is a (directed) divergence, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_(statistics)

Comment: (Divergence).. as mentioned in 'the related Wikipedia article'.

Answer (score 5):

The KL divergence is a [pre-metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Premetrics), given that it satisfies the two properties of pre-metrics

1. $d(x, y) \geq 0, \forall x, y$
2. $d(x, x) = 0, \forall x$

So, given that any pre-metric induces a topology, so does the KL divergence.

The KL divergence is related to other metrics (such as the *Fisher information metric*) or information-theoretic concepts (such as information content, mutual information, Shannon entropy, conditional entropy, and cross-entropy). See also [the related Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence).

Answer (score 1):

It is a divergence, a function that maps two probability densities (or mass function), $p, q$ into $[0, \infty]$ with many special properties.

In particular, KL is a Bregman divergence! Let $\Omega$ be the set of probability densities over your sample space $X$. Choose any function $F:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ that is continuously differentiable and strictly convex, and the function $D_F: \Omega^2 \to \mathbb{R}, \ \ D(p, q) = F(p)-F(q)-\langle \nabla F(q), p-q\rangle $ is a Bregman divergence.

Bregman divergences have many great properties such as being non-negative,  $D_F(p, q) = 0$ iff $p=q$, convex in the first argument, ... (see [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bregman_divergence)).

In particular if you set $F(p) = -\log(p)$, the induced Bregman divergence is indeed KL divergence! Hence, all the properties on that Wikipedia link apply.

Lastly note that as you mentioned, KL divergence is not a metric b/c it doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality. It is not a measure b/c it does not act on sets. It is a divergence.

Comment: ... and has the property that if the distributions are identical, it maps them into $0$.

Comment: While not wrong, this is not particularly helpful

Comment: Agreed.  The basic issue is that plenty of such functions are *not* divergences.  It's kind of like trying to define "mammal" as a "terrestrial life form:" you get a tiny bit of information but not much enlightenment (and it's not completely correct, anyway, because there are non-terrestrial mammals and the KL divergence applies to *any* two probability distributions).

Comment: all fair comments. more content input that should be very useful